Using flutter_maps package, intercative polygons drawn are not all shown , only the last is rendered
I have used flutter_map package:
https://github.com/fleaflet/flutter_map
I have already modified it for my own project in such a way that a user can use 1 click to start drawing, simplifying hovering mouse ( no clicks needed), a 2nd click to stop drawing, followed by either a long press to discard the drawing or a right click to save the polygon.
The problem is that ONLY the last one that is just drawn can be seen and as soon as a new polygon is started to be drawn, the previous one disappeared (all others already hidden ;) )
Any comments please?
FYI, my desired platform is Windows only ...
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_map/flutter_map.dart';
import 'package:flutter_map_example/main.dart';
import 'package:flutter_map_example/misc/tile_providers.dart';
import 'package:flutter_map_example/widgets/drawer/menu_drawer.dart';
import 'package:latlong2/latlong.dart'; 
import 'dart:math';

int  polygonssaved = 1; // one is defined as a constant below

typedef HitValue = ({String title, String subtitle});
 
void writedatajson(List <LatLng> coordinates) async
{
   Geofences geo;

   if (defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.windows)
   { 
        final parsedCoordinates=coordinates.toString().replaceAll('LatLng(latitude:','[').replaceAll(', longitude:',',').replaceAll('), ','],').replaceAll(')',']');
        
        geo= Geofences(1,mycomputerName , DateTime.now().toString(),'myaudio' ,'emeregency','myprovince'  ,parsedCoordinates  ,'active',1);
        geo.writeJsonFile(); 
        }
}

class PolygonPage extends StatefulWidget {

  static const String route = '/polygon';

  const PolygonPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<PolygonPage> createState() => _PolygonPageState();
}

class _PolygonPageState extends State<PolygonPage> {

  bool drawingfinished=true, oncedone=false;
  List<LatLng> mypolygonpoints=List.empty(growable: true);

  static const double pointSize = 65;
  static const double pointY = 250;

  final mapController = MapController();

  LatLng? latLng;

 Polygon<HitValue> buildPolygon(List<LatLng> points, HitValue hitvals)  
 { 
  final Polygon<HitValue> p= Polygon<HitValue>(
                    points:points,
     pattern: StrokePattern.dashed(segments: const [50, 20]),
     // pattern: const StrokePattern.dotted(),

      color: Colors.blue,
      borderColor: Colors.red,
       rotateLabel: true,
     //  label: 'Pre-defined polygon ',
      borderStrokeWidth: 2,
      hitValue: (      title: 'Created at ${DateTime.now()}',       subtitle: '- Nothing really special here...'   ),
                         
      );
       return p;
 }

  final LayerHitNotifier<HitValue> _hitNotifier = ValueNotifier(null);
  List<HitValue>? _prevHitValues;
  List<Polygon<HitValue>>? _hoverGons;
 List<Polygon<HitValue>> polygonsRaw =<Polygon<HitValue>>[ 
                Polygon(
                  points: const [LatLng(-37.927145, 144.984677), LatLng(-37.931937, 144.985144), LatLng(-37.932306, 144.985144), LatLng(-37.932674, 144.985144), LatLng(-37.932859, 144.985144), LatLng(-37.933227, 144.985144), LatLng(-37.933596, 144.985144), LatLng(-37.93378, 144.98491), LatLng(-37.934149, 144.984443), LatLng(-37.934518, 144.984443), LatLng(-37.934886, 144.984209), LatLng(-37.935071, 144.983742), LatLng(-37.935071, 144.983274), LatLng(-37.935439, 144.983274), LatLng(-37.935439, 144.982807), LatLng(-37.935808, 144.982807), LatLng(-37.935808, 144.982573), LatLng(-37.935808, 144.982106), LatLng(-37.935808, 144.981639), LatLng(-37.935808, 144.981405), LatLng(-37.935808, 144.980938), LatLng(-37.935808, 144.98047), LatLng(-37.935623, 144.980236), LatLng(-37.935623, 144.979769), LatLng(-37.935255, 144.979302), LatLng(-37.935255, 144.978834), LatLng(-37.934886, 144.978133), LatLng(-37.934702, 144.977666), LatLng(-37.934702, 144.977198), LatLng(-37.934333, 144.976965), LatLng(-37.934333, 144.976497), LatLng(-37.933965, 144.976497), LatLng(-37.933965, 144.97603), LatLng(-37.93378, 144.97603), LatLng(-37.93378, 144.975563), LatLng(-37.933412, 144.975329), LatLng(-37.933412, 144.974862), LatLng(-37.933043, 144.974862), LatLng(-37.933043, 144.974394), LatLng(-37.933043, 144.974394)],
                pattern: StrokePattern.dashed(segments: const [50, 20]),
                // pattern: const StrokePattern.dotted(),

                  color: Colors.blue,
                  borderColor: Colors.red,
                  rotateLabel: true,
                  // label: 'Pre-defined polygon ',
                  borderStrokeWidth: 2,
                  hitValue: (      title:  'Created at ${DateTime.now()}',     subtitle: '- Nothing really special here...'   ),
                ),
       
 ];
 
  //final List<Polygon<HitValue>> _polygonsRaw = List.empty(growable: true);
 
  late var _polygons =      Map.fromEntries(polygonsRaw.map((e) => MapEntry(e.hitValue, e)));
 

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Draw & Manage Geofences ...')),
      drawer: const MenuDrawer(PolygonPage.route),
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          Flexible(
            child:  FlutterMap(
              mapController: mapController,
              options: MapOptions(
                              keepAlive: true,
                              onPositionChanged: (_, __) => updatePoint(context),

                              onTap: (tapPos, latLng)   =>{   
                                                                  
                                                                  drawingfinished=drawingfinished?false:true, 
                                                                  if (drawingfinished==false) {mypolygonpoints.clear(),// first time click means just started gathering latlngs (previous ones must be deleted)
                                                                                            print('1st click ...> drawing has just started ')},
                                                                  ScaffoldMessenger.maybeOf(context)?.showSnackBar(   SnackBar(duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 100),
                                                                                                                              backgroundColor:Colors.green[400] ,
                                                                                                                              content: Text('Primary tap at $latLng')) ),                                         
                                                                    mypolygonpoints.add(latLng),
                              
                                                                  if (drawingfinished==false)  print('2nd click ...> drawing has just Ended for total number of points  ${mypolygonpoints.length} selected ... ')  //called when the 2nd click (finished drawing indicator) is called reporting number of locations gathered
                                                                    },   

                              onPointerHover: (tapPos, latLng)   =>{   //freehand
                                          print('moved .............'),
                                       if (!drawingfinished)     { 
                                                                           mypolygonpoints.add(latLng),   
                                                                            setState(() => polygonsRaw.add(buildPolygon(mypolygonpoints,(   title:'Created at ${DateTime.now()}',  subtitle: 'the subtitle test'   ))))  ,
                                                                            _polygons =      Map.fromEntries(polygonsRaw.map((e) => MapEntry(e.hitValue, e))),

                                                                           
                                                                          }
                                        },                              

                              onLongPress: (tapPos, latLng)  => {     ScaffoldMessenger.maybeOf(context)?.showSnackBar(   SnackBar(duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 1000),
                                                                                                                                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(   horizontal: 100,     ),  
                                                                                                                                backgroundColor:mypolygonpoints.isNotEmpty ?  Colors.red[400] : Colors.blueAccent,
                                                                                                                                width: 500,
                                                                                                                                behavior: SnackBarBehavior.floating,
                                                                                                                                content: mypolygonpoints.isEmpty ? const Text('No polygons to delete !'): const Text('Polygon Deleted successfully ...') ,
                                                                                                                                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100),     ))), 
                                                                                 
                                                                  if(mypolygonpoints.isNotEmpty &&drawingfinished )
                                                                                      {                
                                                                                    setState(() => polygonsRaw.removeRange(polygonssaved,polygonsRaw.length)),
                                                                                        _polygons =      Map.fromEntries(polygonsRaw.map((e) => MapEntry(e.hitValue, e))),

                                                                                      print('Long press :   ${mypolygonpoints.length} points Deleted --> number of  polygons left :${polygonsRaw.length}'),
 
                                                                                    }
                                                                        
                                        },
                              onSecondaryTap: (tapPos, latLng)  => {   
                                                                                     
                                                                        ScaffoldMessenger.maybeOf(context)?.showSnackBar(   SnackBar(duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 1000),
                                                                                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(   horizontal: 100,     ),  
                                                                                                    backgroundColor:mypolygonpoints.isNotEmpty ?  Colors.red[600] : Colors.greenAccent,
                                                                                                    width: 500,
                                                                                                    behavior: SnackBarBehavior.floating,
                                                                                                    content: mypolygonpoints.isEmpty ? const Text('No polygons to save !'): const Text('Polygon saved successfully ...') ,
                                                                                                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100),     ))), 
                                                                     
                                                                     
                                                                      if(mypolygonpoints.isNotEmpty && drawingfinished)     finalizepolygonsaving(),
                                                                                 
                                                                       
                                                                            },
                              initialCenter: myglobalccp,
                              initialZoom: 20,
                            ),
              children:   [
                              openStreetMapTileLayer,
                                if (latLng != null)
                              MarkerLayer(
                                    markers: [
                                      Marker(
                                        width: pointSize,
                                        height: pointSize,
                                        point: latLng!,
                                        child: const Icon(
                                          Icons.circle,
                                          size: 10,
                                          color: Color.fromARGB(255, 252, 3, 3),
                                        ),
                                      )
                                    ],
                                  ),
                              MouseRegion(
                                hitTestBehavior: HitTestBehavior.deferToChild,
                                cursor: SystemMouseCursors.click,
                                onHover: (_) { 
                                  
                                                  if((!drawingfinished) || mypolygonpoints.isNotEmpty )  return;   // added to avoid unrequired processing fees ( wait till polygon is saved or discarded )

                                                  final hitValues = _hitNotifier.value?.hitValues.toList();
                                                  if (hitValues == null) return;

                                                if (listEquals(hitValues, _prevHitValues)) return;
                                                  _prevHitValues = hitValues;

                                                  final hoverLines = hitValues.map((v) { //  _polygons =      Map.fromEntries(polygonsRaw.map((e) => MapEntry(e.hitValue, e)));
                                                                          final original = _polygons[v]!;

                                                          return Polygon<HitValue>(
                                                                        points: original.points,
                                                                        holePointsList: original.holePointsList,
                                                                        color: Colors.blue,
                                                                        borderStrokeWidth: 2,
                                                                        borderColor: Colors.green,
                                                                        disableHolesBorder: original.disableHolesBorder,
                                                                      );
                                                        }).toList();
                                  setState(() => _hoverGons = hoverLines);
                                },
                                onExit: (_) {if((!drawingfinished) || mypolygonpoints.isNotEmpty )  return;   // added to avoid unrequired processing fees ( wait till polygon is saved or discarded )
                                            _prevHitValues = null;
                                            setState(() => _hoverGons = null);
                                          },
                                child: GestureDetector(
                                          onTap: () =>_openTouchedGonsModal(
                                            'Clicked ',
                                            _hitNotifier.value!.hitValues,
                                            _hitNotifier.value!.coordinate,
                                          ),
                                          onLongPress: () =>{ _openTouchedGonsModal(
                                            'Long press ',
                                            _hitNotifier.value!.hitValues,
                                            _hitNotifier.value!.coordinate,
                                          ), 
                                          },
                                          onSecondaryTap: () => _openTouchedGonsModal(
                                            'Secondary click ',
                                            _hitNotifier.value!.hitValues,
                                            _hitNotifier.value!.coordinate,
                                          ),
                                        child: PolygonLayer(
                                          hitNotifier: _hitNotifier,
                                          simplificationTolerance: 0,
                                          polygons: [...polygonsRaw, ...?_hoverGons],
                                        ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              const Scalebar(
                            textStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 14),
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10, left: 10, bottom: 40),
                            alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                          ),
                          const Scalebar(
                            textStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 14),
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10, left: 10, bottom: 80),
                            alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                            length: ScalebarLength.s,
                          ),
                          const Scalebar(
                            textStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 14),
                            alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                            length: ScalebarLength.s,
                          ),
                          const Scalebar(
                            textStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 14),
                            length: ScalebarLength.xxl,
                          ),
                          const Scalebar(
                            textStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 14),
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10, left: 10, top: 40),
                          ),
                          const Scalebar(
                            textStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 14),
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10, left: 10, top: 80),
                            length: ScalebarLength.s,
                          ),
                            ],
                          ),    ),

          Positioned(
            top: pointY - pointSize / 2,
            left: _getPointX(context) - pointSize / 2,
            child: const IgnorePointer(
              child: Icon(
                Icons.center_focus_strong_outlined,
                size: pointSize,
                color: Color(0xFF0E0E0F),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Positioned(
            top: pointY + pointSize / 2 + 6,
            left: 0,
            right: 0,
            child: IgnorePointer(
              child: Text(
                '(${latLng?.latitude.toStringAsFixed(3)},${latLng?.longitude.toStringAsFixed(3)})',
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                style: const TextStyle(
                  color: Color.fromARGB(255, 4, 67, 255),
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  fontSize: 16,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          )

        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) => updatePoint(context));
  }

  void finalizepolygonsaving(){

 
            setState(() => polygonsRaw.removeRange(polygonssaved,polygonsRaw.length));
           _polygons =      Map.fromEntries(polygonsRaw.map((e) => MapEntry(e.hitValue, e)));

            setState(() => polygonsRaw.add(buildPolygon(mypolygonpoints,(    title:'Created at ${DateTime.now()}',  subtitle: 'the subtitle test'   ))))  ;
              _polygons =      Map.fromEntries(polygonsRaw.map((e) => MapEntry(e.hitValue, e)));

            print('Right clicked (Saving Polygon requested) with: ${mypolygonpoints.length} vertices --> NEW number of polygons  =${polygonsRaw.length}');
            polygonssaved++;    
   }


  void _openTouchedGonsModal(
    String eventType,
    List<HitValue> tappedLines,
    LatLng coords,
  ) {  // if((drawingfinished) && mypolygonpoints.isEmpty )  return; // added to avoid unrequired processing fees ( wait till polygon is saved or discarded )

    showModalBottomSheet<void>(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) => Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            const Text(
              'The Geofence(s)',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
            Text(
              '$eventType at point: (${coords.latitude.toStringAsFixed(6)}, ${coords.longitude.toStringAsFixed(6)})',
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 8),
            Expanded(
              child: ListView.builder(
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  final tappedLineData = tappedLines[index];
                  return ListTile(
                    leading: index == 0
                        ? const Icon(Icons.vertical_align_top)
                        : index == tappedLines.length - 1
                            ? const Icon(Icons.vertical_align_bottom)
                            : const SizedBox.shrink(),
                    title: Text(tappedLineData.title),
                    subtitle: Text(tappedLineData.subtitle),
                    dense: true,
                  );
                },
                itemCount: tappedLines.length,
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 8),
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              child: SizedBox(
                width: double.infinity,
                child: OutlinedButton(
                  onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
                  child: const Text('Close'),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ); 
  }



    void updatePoint(BuildContext context) => setState(() => latLng =
      mapController.camera.pointToLatLng(Point(_getPointX(context), pointY)));

  double _getPointX(BuildContext context) =>
      MediaQuery.sizeOf(context).width / 2;
}

